# How to create a file upload button in Racket?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

So I'm writing a small Racket application that will parse a (very poorly formatted) .txt file and output a .csv that can be worked with in Excel.  The first thing I want to do is open up a small window with a button that opens a file dialog so the user can select the file to be converted (just like any program that launches an open file selection dialog).  I've looked around online and can't find anything on this.  This is going to be a native application, so the stuff I have found on POSTing to webservers isn't relevant.  How can you do this in Racket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedures [`get-file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=get-file#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._get-file%29%29) and [`put-file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=get-file#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._put-file%29%29) exist in `#lang racket/gui`. Both can be used to obtain file pathnames from users via a dialog. `get-file` is styled towards selecting existing files, while `put-file` is directed towards creating new ones.

Consider the following example that does the following:

- It creates a window containing a "Select File" button.
- When button is clicked, a dialog will appear to select a file (can be the .txt file for conversion).
- Once the text file is selected, it will open another dialog to select a file to save converted data on (can be the .csv file).

---

```
#lang racket/gui

;; Prints file's contents line by line
(define (print-each-line input-file)
  (define line (read-line input-file))
  (unless (eof-object? line)
    ;; 'line' here represents a line of txt file's contents
    ;; The line can be processed/modified to any desired output, but
    ;; for the purposes of this example, the line will simply be
    ;; printed the way it is without any "processing".
    (println line)
    (print-each-line input-file)))

;; Convert txt to csv by printing each line of txt
;; to the csv file using print-each-line (above)
(define (convert txt csv)
  (define in (open-input-file txt))
  (with-output-to-file csv
    (lambda () (print-each-line in)))
  (close-input-port in))

;; Make a frame by instantiating the frame% class
(define frame (new frame% [label "Example"]))

;; Make a button in the frame
(new button% [parent frame]
             [label "Select File"]
             ;; Callback procedure for a button click:
             [callback
              (lambda (button event)
                (define txt (get-file))
                (define csv (put-file))
                (convert txt csv))])

;; Show the frame by calling its show method
(send frame show #t)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This is exactly what I needed to learn how this works.  I'm reading more about frames now.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what are you need. If you want know how to work with files see [File ports](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html?q=wit-open#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._call-with-input-file%29%29) section, but if you need to know how to create and use GUI objects see [Windowing](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html?q=window). Build GUI applications based on GTK (wich used in racket implemenation) it's not trivial task for a newbe user. It's not my business, but I think if you take some RAD (such as Lazarus for object pascal, MS Visual Studio for C#), you can doing your task faster and easier than write GUI as text without some experience.